# Repo-level security permissions using az devops CLI?

Tags: security, azure-devops, permissions, repository, devops

Is it possible through az devops CLI (for ex: az devops security permissions commands) to set repo security settings at the repo level so that a repo may only be visible/accessible to specific users (and admin) in the project?

I am essentially looking for commands which will grant a specific user access to a specific repo @ repo-level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am essentially looking for commands which will grant a specific user access to a specific repo @ repo-level

You can use [az devops security permission update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/security/permission?view=azure-cli-latest#az-devops-security-permission-update) Azure Cli and use `2e9eb7ed-3c0a-47d4-87c1-0ffdd275fd87` as the id parameter:

```
az devops security permission update --id 2e9eb7ed-3c0a-47d4-87c1-0ffdd275fd87
                                     --subject
                                     --token
                                     [--allow-bit]
                                     [--deny-bit]
                                     [--detect {false, true}]
                                     [--merge {false, true}]
                                     [--org]
```

> Is it possible through az devops CLI to set repo security settings at the repo level so that a repo may only be visible/accessible to specific users in the project?

Yes. Here is an example. Please replace the braces and their contents with your own information:

```
az devops security permission update --id 2e9eb7ed-3c0a-47d4-87c1-0ffdd275fd87 --subject {email address or group descriptor} --token repoV2/{project id}/{repository id}/ --allow-bit 2 --merge true
```

Please notice the `--allow-bit 2`. The number `2` refer to the **Read** permission of a repository.

So if you want to let a user/group can access to a repository, you need to use `--allow-bit 2`. If you want to let a user/group **cannot** access to a repository, you need to use `--deny-bit 2`.

Comment: thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. I used az devops security permission show to get the list of permissions bits that are useable for allow-bit or deny-bit